# cannot start Android emulator on Eclipse even though there are no errors

Tags: android, eclipse, load, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run one of the Android sample apps in Eclipse. I've been through all the possible errors, and now I was finally able to run without any of them. But still, nothing works, and the emulator just has the "android" sign shining on it.
The log I have is:

```
[2011-12-26 21:18:50 - AccelerometerPlayActivity] ------------------------------ 
[2011-12-26 21:18:50 - AccelerometerPlayActivity] Android Launch! 
[2011-12-26 21:18:50 - AccelerometerPlayActivity] adb is running normally. 
[2011-12-26 21:18:50 - AccelerometerPlayActivity] Performing com.example.android.accelerometerplay.AccelerometerPlayActivity activity launch 
[2011-12-26 21:19:26 - AccelerometerPlayActivity] Uploading AccelerometerPlayActivity.apk onto device 'emulator-5554' 
[2011-12-26 21:19:26 - AccelerometerPlayActivity] Installing AccelerometerPlayActivity.apk... 
[2011-12-26 21:19:28 - AccelerometerPlayActivity] Success! 
[2011-12-26 21:19:28 - AccelerometerPlayActivity] Starting activity com.example.android.accelerometerplay.AccelerometerPlayActivity on device emulator-5554
```

I already changed the configuration of the AVD, created a new one, etc. Nothing seems of any help
Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: From the console log, it seems it takes about 38 minutes from `Android Launch!` to `Starting Activity`. I'd seriously begin to wonder if I was using the right configuration and if I had enough RAM. How much have you got?

Comment: I used 256 as RAM size. It through me some RAM errors for other sizes I used. Also, from Android Launch to Starting Activity it took a few seconds, it got stuck after the Starting Activity message...

Comment: My bad. I read mm:ss as hh:mm. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to 'downgrade' the emulator.

I'm assuming you aren't programming for the newest android 4.0+ or something like that,
(Samsung galexy s is 2.0 or 2.2, I think).
When I had that problem it helped me alot.

try it :)

Comment: can you remind me how to do it? 4.0 is the only Android option I see

Comment: go to the SDK Manager, and in stall all (or android ~2.0-2.2 API's).
Than go to tools (in the SDK Managerand), choose the first option->new->target (chhose android 2.2 API 8  OR 2.0 for that matter).

Comment: Did it help to fix the problem ?

Comment: I tried 2.2 and 2.3 and it didn't work - it got the Android working but couldn't start the app itself. On the other hand, I dl'd the latest API at the same time, and somehow everything works there. So, close enough :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem a long time ago. Make sure that path to your android sdk (or adb) doesn't contain any national symbols (cyrillic in my case) except English.

If you using Windows, also check your profile name.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a little more.... in some computers, the emulator wait up to 10 minutes to run first time. Its a lot of time, but, next compile time, don´t close it, just clear proyect, build all and run, and it will work.